# automatically exposing database tables through web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

Is there any framework or tool to generate web services (WCF) access to all the non transactional tables in my database? something like asp.net dynamic data but with web services, I need to do this for homologation with other systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) - you can easily create a model of your database (Entity Framework, Linq-to-SQL, custom) and expose all tables and their contents via a WCF REST interface to any HTTP browser.

Answer (score 2):

Yep - WCF Data Services is the way to go. Also known as "OData".

Check out this MIX10 Video (free) by Pablo Castro (MS Architect) who covers it:
http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT12

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/)?  I haven't used it, but from what I read it sounds like it'll be close.  Although emphasis is on Silverlight, it will play nice with other endpoints.